# Moving all rows to be columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to move all rows to be a columns the screen shot attached.

I need the final result to be like

```
Owner    Status     People             Date         ......
Diane    Over-Due    Diane Campbell     2020-01-21  .......
```

How to do this using a SQL query.

[image: screenshot]

My attempt:

```
select * from(
SELECT  [Column_text],[Column_title] FROM [BoardItem_ColumnValues] 
where Item_id='412604123') as s
PIVOT
(
count([Column_title])
for [Column_title] IN ([Owner],[Status],[People],[Date],[Week],[Contact Name],[Acct # / DVM State License],[Acct login credentials],[Contact Email],[Contact Phone],[New Acct # / DEA],[Previous SP abd Rebates In Place],[Parent ACCT])
) AS PVT
```

my result is 
[image: my result]

i need it like

so if i remove count what should i put to do the below scenario!

> Owner    Status     People             Date         ...... Diane
>   Over-Due    Diane Campbell     2020-01-21  .......

Comment: [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I tried it, but i can't make any results .

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: This is a text book example for a PIVOT. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Here's what i have tried.

select * from(
SELECT  [Column_text],[Column_title] FROM [BoardItem_ColumnValues] 
where Item_id='412604123') as s
PIVOT
(
[Column_text]
for [Column_title] IN (Owner,Status,People,Date,Week,Contact Name,Acct # / DVM State License,Acct login credentials,Contact Email,Contact Phone,New Acct # / DEA,Previous SP abd Rebates In Place,Parent ACCT)
) AS PVT

Comment: What did you receive as output from your query: An error, an incorrect resultset, random numbers, ???. Please show an example (preferably the exact output) of what was generated by SQL Server when you ran your query.

Comment: In future please edit additional info directly into the question. Also I assume you are using square brackets around the multi-word column names?

Comment: @LaughingVergil attached!

Comment: Rather than count([Column_title])  use max(Column_Text)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks very much thats it! it worked !